# How to show an event event on fullcalendar based on dayname

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Lets say i want to have an event on every "Monday" from 9am-11am is it possible in Full calendar control if yes then how?

Comment: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/ read full documentation. You can set event in days

Comment: Monday means lots of dates. Full calender will not know which monday you mean to dispaly the event.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli can we just set the background color for a time range i am trying to solve a availability time like thing here